# Drush & Fbconnect on Windows 7

Tags: drush

I have installed fbconnect module with Drupal 6 on Windows 7. Everything seems to be working fine. From front end I can login to my site via fbconnect. However when I try to run and drush script, for example drush updatedb, it throws me following fbconnect error

[image: FBconnect Error Messages]

**Message is**

> WD php: Exception: Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension. in
>   require_once() (line 19 of 
>   E:\wamp\www\foo\sites\default\modules\contrib_modified\fbconnect\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php).
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

Edit: Curl is enabled but still I am getting this error, please see below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Drush uses a different php.ini than the web server does.  The phpinfo() you are looking at above is from your web server's php.ini.  Run `drush status` to see the path to the php.ini that Drush is using.  Then, compare the two and copy directives from the web server php.ini, such as the directives that enable the CURL PHP extension and memory_limit, and put them in Drush's cli php.ini.  Then everything should work fine.

Comment: This makes total sense, can't believe I didn't manage to put two and two together on this one!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error. You need to get the CURL PHP extension.

[How do I install cURL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181082/how-do-i-install-curl-on-windows)

If it's installed, then make sure it's enabled.

Comment: please check the screenshot above it is already enabled but still I am getting error. It is only happening with drush

Comment: If you're running WAMP 64-bit, then apparently the packaged extension is broken.  Try [this](http://www.morningtime.com/kb/188) from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465586/facebook-needs-the-curl-php-extension) on StackOverflow